# C++ Comparing column elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Trying to make a C++ program which makes 2 different size arrays, so far so good, yet after that I need to make 2 functions which compare the numbers in each column (for specific array, you can choose which one at the start) and printf the number of columns where all the numbers are different form each other.
So here's the deal, one function needs to use array indexes but the other one array pointers.

This is how far I got with index one.

```
analyze_ind(int array[row][col], int r, int c,int column)
{  
    column=0;     
    int i,j;

    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        fail=0;

        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            if(array[i][j]==array[i-1][j]) 
            {
               fail=1;
               break;
            }
        }

        if(fail==0)
        {
            column++;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Needless to say this code is wrong, not sure if only due to the if statement or there is some other mistakes as well. 
I would be very thankful if someone can look in to this, and correct me on this one.

```
analyze_rad(int *array, int r, int c, int column)
```

Comment: did you post the whole function? You're missing a closing `}`

Comment: What's wrong with your code.  Is is not resulting in the output that it's supposed to?

Comment: What Im asking here is that I do not get how to write IF statement so it checks if there are similar elements in the column!
In my code it checks columns first element with second then second with third which is wrong!

Comment: How are `row` and `col`, in the function signature, defined?

Comment: Perhaps this article can help you a bit 
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-compare-two-columns-matches-differences/

Answer (score 0):

In a two dimensional array declared as:

```
  a[row][column]
```

you can search by keeping the column indices constant.

For example, the following `if` expression tests values in columns 1 and 2 *in the same row* for equality:

```
if (a[j][0] == a[j][1])
```

For searching column 6 for a given value, the `if` statement looks like:

```
if (a[j][5] == value)
```